# Is it possible to hide API credentials in python source code?

Tags: python, security, pyinstaller

I have a python app that makes a call to a web API to collect some data, processes the data displays it on a front end. Unfortunately, the credentials that are needed to access the API also give access to a bunch of sensitive information.

Therefore, I was wondering if there was any way to connect to the API in a way that doesn't let people with access to the python code reconstruct the credentials. I have found some posts about encrypting the data outside the app and decrypting it inside the app, but it seems to me that this would require revealing the decryption method in the python code, which would mean that everyone could simply reconstruct it.

Comment: Create something to sit in the middle, store the credentials there away from the user: [user] -> [your proxy api] -> [real api]

Comment: This seems like a sensible approach, although it basically means setting up and maintaining an intermediary server only for this purpose. Are there any tutorials or packages that are specifically designed to make this process simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using .env file with e.g. python-dotenv library.

`mycode.py` file:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

my_var=os.getenv("MYHIDDEN_VAR")
```

`.env` file:

```
MYHIDDEN_VAR='REAL VALUE'
```

`.env.example` file:

```
MYHIDDEN_VAR='OBSCURED VALUE'
```

Comment: Ok, but would this work if I packaged the app with pyinstaller and sent it to someone else? Wouldn't that require me to send the .env along with everything else, making it easily retrievable for everyone in possession of the package?

Comment: Actually yes. So, as mentioned above, having intermediate API and authentication for that usage is the only feasible solution I can think of. It is not that big of the task to code with e.g. Flask or Node.js. The only downside is that you have to have that intermediate server routing the data. But when you have set up your own API, it is quite a easy to maintain.